# How does Corki's passive work?

Tags: league-of-legends

Is the true damage on top of his AD or build into his damage?

Here is the passive for reference:

> (Innate): Corki's autoattacks deal 10% of his total physical damage
>   before armor adjustment, as additional true damage to minions,
>   monsters, and champions.

If I had 100 AD and shoot a target with 0 armor, does it then deal 100 damage hence 90% from AD and rest from true damage or does it deal 110 damage because of 100 AD+10% from passive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's in addition to his AD. Similar to and item like Wit's End, you'll see two numbers when you hit someone (100 + 10 = 110, in your example)[image]